# every Nth bit of on first number(expressed binary) forms the other number

Tags: binary

I want to simplify a condition that checks if every Nth bit of on first number(expressed binary) forms the other number (expressed binary). One way to express it is [condition expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Fzl.gif). Another way is [arithmetic expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKPUd.gif).

Is there any way to simplify this condition so that it would not involve sum(Σ) or quantifier? It would be easy if there were some elementary function that adds(or removes) N bits after each bit. I don't need program in any programing language, that does it, but a function in common mathematical symbols. It would also be good answer if someone explained why it is impossible.

for example condition is satisfied if n1=4196 n2=23 N=3, because:

4196=**1**10**0**10**1**10**1**10**1**<sub>2</sub> and 23=**10111**<sub>2</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I  don't think you can do this with a formula. You will need a loop of some kind since you have to compare the binary expansions.

One possible algorithm: insert $0$ bits between the bits of $n_2$, mask the corresponding bits of $n_1$, then check for equality.

It's the insertion that requires a loop. You're essentially using the base $2$ digits to find the corresponding number if you think of them as base $2^N$ digits.

Note: I think this is cleaner if you count digits starting from the right rather than the left.